# Check log file for error only for last 10 mins

Tags: linux, shell

I've a log file with below text,

```
[2022-05-05T22:25:58,523] Text/debug data
```

I want to fetch log data for errors in only last 10 mins to configure in cron.
How to fetch the data only for last 10 mins.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do post your tried efforts in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d=$(date -d -10min '+[%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,000]')

awk -v "d=$d" '$1 >= d {p=1} p' logfile
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, 
but somehow this is not working it is giving the complete log file as output.

Also how to grep any specific error from that output data.

Comment: Welcome Detroit, the answer is correct to the question input provided for Linux platform. Check the answer with the provided input not your input.